# Halakhah for one in the process of converting?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

Shalom.

I am pursuing conversion, but have recently encountered a problem in my avodah. I have found that Noachidism is ‘too little’ and full Torah observance ‘too much’ for me. Both extremes have led me into great trouble recently. I was wondering therefore if someone could explain the halakhah for one in the process of converting. Which additional mitzvot ought the prospective convert add to his avodah first, and in what order should they be added? And what degree of observance should a prospective convert be ‘up to’ before being circumcised / immersed? If anyone could clarify these matters for me I would be most grateful.

Comment: I would imagine this would be a personal preference.You should also be in touch with a certified Beis Din which would guide you as to what level of observance you should  be at before they'll finalize your conversion. Having a Rav is also pretty necessary for this process and beyond.

Comment: @robev - thanks, I’ll see what I can sort out with my LOR. T